# What is the variance of this random variable?

Tags: probability, random-variables

A clerk drops $n$ matching pairs of letters and envelopes. He then places the letters into
the envelopes in a random order. Let $X$ be the number of correctly matched pairs. Find the
variance of $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y_i=1$ if the $i$-th letter is in the right envelope, and let $Y_i=0$ otherwise. Then
$X=Y_1+Y_2+\cdots+Y_n$.

Now $E(X)$ is easy to find using the linearity of expectation. It remains to find $E(X^2)$.

Square $Y_1+Y_2+\cdots+Y_n$. We get $\sum Y_i^2$ plus a bunch of "mixed" terms. If we can find the expectation of each, we will be finished.

Calculation of $E(Y_i^2)$ is easy, since $Y_i^2=Y_i$. To find $E(Y_iY_j)$, find the probability that $Y_i=1$ and $Y_j=1$.

Comment: $Y_iY_j$ still have 0 or 1 values, so $E[Y_iY_j]=1/n$?